# Build failed flutter project in Xcode, packages not found

Tags: xcode, dart

I'm trying to help with a Flutter project specifically the iOS side not so much the android side. This project takes advantage of Flutter packages though when trying to build in Xcode it is failing the build because the 'file' was not found.

The package is included in the pub spec files, flutter has gotten the packages and **when building from terminal the build passes. It is only when trying to build from Xcode that the build is failing.**

One example error message reads:

> "'fast_qr_reader_view/FastQrReaderViewPlugin.h' file not found"

on an import line for that file.

Due to the project building ok in terminal but not Xcode am I wrong to believe this is some Xcode configuration issue? If it is an Xcode config issue would anyone know where to fix this issue.

Thanks all!

Comment: I am having the same issue with a recent and fresh installation of Flutter and Xcode. My project uses libraries like path provider, sqflite and url_launcher. The project compiles fine for Android but spots out the same error as above when compiling for iOS through XCode.